# Laravel retrieving single related attribute

Tags: laravel, api, laravel-5, eloquent, relationships

I have a laravel app that allows users to post posts. Each post has a price (stored as an integer), and belongs to a university, which in turn belongs to a country, which has a currency.

Every-time I retrieve the posts, I want to return the currency as well. I could do `with('university.country')` but that would return all the details for both the university and country.

I could add a `getCurrencyAttribute` and define the logic there, but that seems not what mutators are for, especially since if I get all the posts, each post will further run two of its own queries just to get the currency. That's 3 queries to get one post, which quickly takes its toll when returning more than 10 posts.

```
public function getCurrencyAttribute() {
        return $this->university->country->currency;
    }

    public function getPriceAttribute($value) {
        return "{$this->currency}{$value}";
    }
```

^ example above: no need for `appends` because `price` is automatically overwritten. This is the problem as seen on DebugBar (two new queries are being called on the Post model, which while expected, becomes inefficient when retrieving lots of posts):
[image]

What's the best way to get a single related field, every-time?

[Full code on GitHub.](http://github.com/mwargan/JustBookr)

Comment: Can you show your exact query?

Comment: The Eloquent query is pretty simple initially: `Post::get()`. See the full code on GitHub :)! Currently using the `with` method to get the currency, but it seems inefficient.

Comment: You could use exactly accessors, they are for getting a custom attribute value from the model.

Answer (score 0):

You can limit the eager loading columns:

```
Post::with('webometricUniversity:uni-id,country_id',  
    'webometricUniversity.country:id,currency')->get();
```

If you always need it, add this to your `Post` model:

```
protected $appends = ['currency'];

protected $with = ['webometricUniversity:uni-id,country_id',  
    'webometricUniversity.country:id,currency'];

public function getCurrencyAttribute() {
    return $this->webometricUniversity->country->currency;
}
```

Then you can just use `Post::get()` and `$post->currency`.

Comment: I could - but ideally I always need the currency when retrieving the price, so I'd like to set it up in the model so it's always pulled.

Comment: I extended my answer.

Comment: Looks good and while I haven't tried it yet it looks like it'll work great! The only thing is that it just *looks* off to me in the sense that I would've expected laravel to already some implementation or helper that deals with my issue - it just seems like a common case especially on super-normalized db's

Comment: How is `$with` *not* the "implementation or helper that deals with my issue"?

Comment: Yeah I guess you're right :P Just curious then if I set `$with` in the model as you showed above, and then call `with('webometricUniversity')` again in the controller to get all university details, will the table be hit twice or will laravel merge the `with`s? Do you think this is even the right approach to currency and pricing in a db :P?

Comment: They get merged and `with()` has priority over `$with`.

Comment: If you *always* need the currency, it might be worth the denormalization.

Comment: Ok the code definitely works, but I'd like to retrieve it flat, not nested, aka have the currency field just by the price field and not nested under webometricUniversity.country. How'd I do that? I literally just need the currency field...

Comment: You use an [accessor](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-mutators#defining-an-accessor): `getCurrencyAttribute`: `return $this->webometricUniversity->country->currency;`

Comment: Yes that definitely works. I saw on a few articles, as I mentioned in the question, that using mutators/accessors for that isn't a good idea and not what they were intended for... but if it works it works ;)! If you update your answer also include `protected $appends = [
    'currency'
];` so others can see how to always attach the attribute ;)

Comment: I updated my answer. I don't see any reason why that would be a bad idea.

Comment: Just ran into something. When calling a list of posts, each post further executes the query to get a university, then a country, totalling 2 new (unwanted) queries per post instead of 1 query to get all posts and the currency... Any thoughts?

Comment: Are you using eager loading?

Comment: No, I need it as an attribute, as it overrides the default price value... Eager loading would take me back to square one. Could I eager load an attribute?

Comment: Can you add the code you are using to your question?

Comment: Just did :) Also I updated the whole code on GitHub which could provide a bit more insight :)

Comment: Where do you access `currency` and/or `price`?

Comment: By calling `Post::get()` in the PostsController, in the simplest sense. The model already has a price field, so when I get the price attribute it just overwrites the value with the new one, as in the question. On GitHub its a little more expanded but you'll notice I don't need to call the price attribute specifically: https://github.com/mwargan/JustBookr/blob/master/app/Http/Controllers/PostsController.php

Comment: `Post::get()` executes queries for `university` and `country`?

Comment: Well by getting the posts, it automatically calls the getPriceAttribute, which then in turn queries the `university`, and then the `country` for each post retrieved... So as far as I see and the debugbar tells me, yes, it executes the other two queries once for each post returned.

Comment: I can't reproduce that.

Comment: Strange... what could help here? Adding some screenshots of debugbars queries?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170815/discussion-between-jonas-staudenmeir-and-michal).